# What concentration of sulfur hexafluoride is safe to inhale

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

I want to do a density demonstration, and I want to inhale helium and sulfur hexafluoride as a fun demonstration. I am open to using any source to purchase from, and money is not an issue (but preferably as inexpensive as possible), but what concentration should I buy (what concentration is safe to inhale), and from where?

Comment: $SF_6$ is available from science supply companies like Flinn.  It's quite expensive, even for a lecture bottle. (~$350 for a bottle, or 70 per balloon.)  You could also order a larger bottle from a company like Praxair.

Comment: As a safety precaution, this site recommends a few deep breaths of pure oxygen first to saturate your lungs.    That sounds like sound common sense to me.    https://www.stevespanglerscience.com/lab/experiments/heavy-gas-sulfur-hexafluoride-sf6/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm afraid this answer doesn't address where you can get $\ce{SF6}$, as I don't know any suppliers myself (it would probably help to specify where you are, though). I just want to straighten out the safety details and make sure you (and anyone else who reads this in the future) know what you're doing. All chemistry experiments can take a turn for the worse if done without adequate preparation.

Pure sulfur hexafluoride is a rather chemically inert gas (unlike the related but very toxic sulfur tetrafluoride $\ce{SF4}$ and disulfur decafluoride $\ce{S2F10}$), and it can be safely handled in regular situations. Decomposition of $\ce{SF6}$ usually requires aggressive conditions, [such as exposure to molten sodium metal at 200°C](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v193/n4814/abs/193473a0.html). There are some situations where $\ce{SF6}$ reacts at low temperatures, but that requires [irradiation with deep-UV photons](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/134/10/10.1063/1.3560908?ver=pdfcov) or [direct contact with solvated electrons from alkali metals dissolved in ammonia](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic50018a033). I don't suppose you'll have to worry about such situations. It also seems that $\ce{SF6}$ can decompose into a small amount of the other aforementioned toxic sulfur fluorides [if it is exposed to electrical arcs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_hexafluoride#Dielectric_medium), but since it is an electrically insulating gas, [the electric fields required for arcing are even higher than in air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u19QfJWI1oQ#t=51s), so this also shouldn't be a problem.

All in all, both pure $\ce{SF6}$ and helium are very unlikely to cause chemical damage to the body, even indirectly. However, **that doesn't imply they are completely safe**. Of course, they can still act as an asphyxiant simply by displacement of oxygen in the lungs (**[make sure to read this!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inert_gas_asphyxiation)**). *Be aware that the brain is incapable of directly measuring the oxygen content in your blood*, and instead measures oxygenation rather indirectly, by the amount of carbon dioxide. **It is possible to faint and even die from hypoxia without any warning**. Additionally, since $\ce{SF6}$ is relatively heavy, it requires more effort from your diaphragm muscles to expel from your lungs, making $\ce{SF6}$ inhalation slightly more dangerous than helium.

As a safety measure, *do not take consecutive breaths in the non-oxygenated gas and do not spend more than 5 seconds without inhaling air*. While your lungs are devoid of oxygen, not only are they unable to transport oxygen into your blood, *the lungs actually work in reverse and help expel oxygen from your blood*. After performing the trick, take deep breaths in regular air for a minute or two before trying it again, to be sure all the previously inhaled $\ce{SF6}$ or helium has exited your lungs and your oxygen supply has returned to normal. Hyperventilating before or after inhaling $\ce{SF6}$/helium is likely a bad idea, as it further messes with the balance of oxygen and carbon dioxide in the blood. You should avoid any possibility of becoming light-headed and fainting, especially if you decide to do the trick multiple times. Also be mindful that the gasses can accumulate in poorly ventilated spaces, with $\ce{SF6}$ being a particular problem as it will tend to stay close to the ground and disperse with more difficulty.

If you're going through the trouble to get $\ce{SF6}$, you should do the floating aluminium boat display, too. It's pretty cool! [Here's another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzLX96VWTkc) showing you can even pour the gas into the boat and make it sink.

Comment: I've seen people who inhale $\ce{SF6}$ invert themselves afterwards, either by lying "upside down" on an inclined surface, or by doing a handstand, etc., and then breath in and out deeply a few times.  The idea was that the inversion helped expel the $\ce{SF6}$ from the lungs.